# credit someone for doing something

Tags: prepositions

This is from [a news article](https://www.npr.org/2023/05/03/1173723661/atlanta-shooting-police-updates-medical-building).

> Schierbaum reported earlier in the day that witnesses helped by
> calling to report sightings of the alleged suspect in Atlanta and
> elsewhere in Cobb County when he was on the run. Officials credited
> this, along with technology, **to** helping track Patterson's location.

Considering this example of 'credit' [(verb 2) in the Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/credit_2),

> *Ray Charles is largely credited for creating soul music.*

I think the '**to**' should be replaced with 'for' to say that somebody is responsible for doing something.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the news article, the word "to" should instead read "with".

We can give credit to someone, we can credit them, they can be credited with things, and things can be credited them, or to them.

(edit: this was a total revision)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: The question said "I think 'to' should be replaced with 'for'" This is incorrect on two counts: it's not necessary to replace to with for, and if you do so, you have to change the structure of the sentence. It's therefore at best misleading to say "Of course, you're right". I see what you are getting at, but you need to explain more clearly, with examples,  that the sentence structure must be modified if a different preposition is to be used.

Comment: I've improved the answer; hopefully I've done nothing wrong by changing it completely after OP accepted it

Comment: @JavaLatte Thank you very much. What's the difference in sentence structure between these two sentences. 1. Officials credited this, along with technology, for helping track Patterson's location. 2. We have to credit all the rain we've had for saving the crops. [link](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/credit+someone+for+something)

Comment: You can totally get away with them; the pattern is sort of breaking up.